# Prevent iTunes from showing video preview frames

Tags: itunes, preview, podcasts, album-art

By default, iTunes video podcasts display their album art as preview frames, rather than the embedded album art that ships with the file.  I have been manually replacing the image with each new episode, but that is very tedious.  Is there a way to prevent iTunes from displaying preview frames in this manner?

There is no Secrets entry for this and I haven't been able to find anybody as anal-retentive about this subject as I am.  Surely someone must exist out there.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a setting to force iTunes to do this.

This actually depends on the the podcast creator and how they embed the album art into their video files.  So, if you aren't getting album art displayed, the issue is on the creator's end and not on yours.